# Parse_url and remove slash only on first folder only?

Tags: php

PHP dummy here. 
Let's say that I have my domain like this:`http://www.domain.com/somefolder/index.html` so now i need to make it like **this** :`somefolder/index.html`

In order to do so I am using following code:

```
<?php $urlparts = parse_url("http://www.domain.com/somefolder/index.html");
$extracted = $urlparts['path'];
print $extracted;?>
```

Now I am getting output like this: `/somefolder/index.html` 
what I like to to do is to **remove first slash only** so that it looks like this:
 **`somefolder/index.html`**, it would be also nice that if I can get the same result (removed slash on first folder but not the other's) even if I have more folders like this: **`other_folder/somefolder/index.html`** or **`other_folder/yet_another_folder/somefolder/index.html`**.

Is there a nice person who can help a dummy like me? THX!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
echo ltrim($extracted, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [ltrim](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.ltrim.php&ei=TGSmUdjXK-jhiwKx4oHQCQ&usg=AFQjCNGwPaJwyUPz_mb1tLcNFS2TLvVxng&sig2=SSVilravAnK1G3inagIpWw&bvm=bv.47244034,d.cGE).

```
<?php 
$urlparts = parse_url("http://www.domain.com/somefolder/index.html");
$extracted = ltrim( $urlparts['path'], '/' );
print $extracted;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
if(substr($extracted, 0, 1) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
    $extracted = substr($extracted, 1);
```